# PHP gets commented out by the browser

Tags: php

I have created a contact.php file with a standard html form but used PHP to retrieve the information entered and to create the email.

The page currently works on one of my websites but when I've copied the file and not changed anything on it but the browser comments it out.

I've looked online for some way around this but all I could find is saying its a problem with the server, both the website are on the same server so that is not the problem.

I've tried putting add handler into my htaccess file as recommended by some people and this has had no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Heres My code

```
$ToEmail = 'email@hotmail.co.uk'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Website Enquiry '; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html;"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "<strong>Name:</strong> <br />".$_POST["yourname"]."<br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "<strong>Email:</strong><br /> ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "<strong>Phone Number:</strong> <br /> ".$_POST["Telephone-Number"]."<br>";
$heard = $_POST['heard'];
foreach($_POST['heard'] as $value) {
$heard_msg .= "$value, ";   
}
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "<strong>How they heard about us:</strong><br /> ".$heard_msg."<br>";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "<strong>Enquiry:</strong> <br /> ".nl2br($_POST["Message"])."<br>"; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
echo '<h1>Thanks for you Enquiry</h1>'; 
echo '<p>Please carry on browsing our site</p>'; 
echo '<a href="http://www.website.com/"> Return to home page</a>';
```

All inside a php if statement starting with 'php'

Comment: By commented out you mean the client receives your PHP code?

Comment: Do you use short open tag (`<?`)?

Comment: Please paste your conde in your question, but if i understand correctly, then what Maxim said must be the issue, you either used <? instead of <?php or you actaully deleted the opening that, but please paste your code.

Comment: can you paste your code to let us see what is going wrong

Comment: Can you show us what you're seeing in the browser? e.g. a screen shot of the problem?

Comment: I cant add screen shot as I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 5):

Browsers shouldn't comment out PHP, they shouldn't even see PHP.

Most likely, what you are experiencing is that the `<?` is not being parsed by the PHP engine and being delivered to the browser. The browser is then treating it as an unknown tag and ignoring it.

The solutions are:

1. Don't use short tags as they are not turned on for all PHP installations. If you have `<? some code` change it to `<?php some code`.
2. Make sure you are trying to run your PHP on a server that supports PHP.

Comment: All my <? are <?php tags :/

And the server not the problem as my other website is working fine with the same code.

Comment: @M.f Does the file end in a `.php` extension‽

Comment: yeah please visit http://www.adeltd.co.uk/contact.php - since i cant add screen shot

Comment: Either you've written a PHP program designed to output PHP source code, or PHP isn't running on that file. That could be because the server doesn't support it at all (although you say that isn't the case) or because it isn't configured to support it for that file.

Comment: how can I get it to be supported for the file?

Comment: That depends on why it isn't supported in the first place. Look at your server configuration. Look at your error logs.

Comment: I've just checked the server configuration again and there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting server probably doesn't support PHP, this is why it is interpreted as comments.

Take a look at your package and see if it should support it.