# my .PHP file doesnt seem to work

Tags: php

i have a rather simple .PHP file with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<p>hello world</p>
 <?php echo "test";
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

yet when i run it all i see is "hello world", i checked firebug and it showed me this [image]

and in chrome it simply comments the php out

[image]

am i missing something important here?

Comment: When are you seeing the change from what you typed to the commented out version? Is this the result of posting it to a server or is this what your software is doing?

Comment: simply saved it as .PHP and ran in a browserr

Comment: How about PHP errors logs? Have you tried taking a look in there?

Comment: "How" are you accessing it, via `http://localhost/file.php` or `file://` ?

Comment: The messages below from others here are correct, you need to install a web server on your computer for it to work... one with PHP included.

Comment: thanks guys, i knew i was missing something rather essential.

Comment: @AndréDaniel, lol im new to php, i knew i was missing something big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is an pre-processed, interpreted language which means a web server (like apache) with the PHP interpreter installed must serve it to you. You must install a webserver on your local machine and access it via a URL like `http://localhost`. PHP cannot be viewed the same way as locally-served HTML files (like what happens when you double click them) through the `file://` prototcol.

But never fear, it is not hard to get a webserver installed. Try something like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), which will install Apache, PHP, and MySQL for you and give you a nifty little control panel.

Comment: and then how would i run a .php file?

Comment: XAMPP will install on your main disk at `/xampp` by default, where you can go into that folder and find a shortcut to `htdocs` where you may place files. For example, a `test.php` placed in the `htdocs` folder will be accessible at `http://localhost/test.php`.

Comment: i put it in, but Firefox cant connect, is there a tutorial on this?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing  PHP. Where is the file located? Are you trying this in a server?

If you are new to PHP I recommend you using WAMP or LAMP, it's the easiest way to start using the languague.

Comment: i saved this on my computer as a `.PHP`, am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, your computer doesn't have PHP installed. What's your operative system?

Comment: Well, then I recommend you to install [Easy PHP](http://www.easyphp.org/). Download the Delevopment version. Then read the docs, it's really easy, but read the docs if you have any doubts.

Comment: I forgot about that one, I have used WAMP, XAMPP and Easy PHP -- all are great for what you need. Easy PHP is a good one for sure.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight  Here is a installation link of [link]http://www.wikihow.com/Install-XAMPP-for-Windows[/link] that gives you an idea how to install it. second use small letter for php tags eg: <?php  ?>

Answer (score 1):

A quote from here [PHP gets commented out by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582505/php-gets-commented-out-by-the-browser)

> Browsers shouldn't comment out PHP, they shouldn't even see PHP.
>
> Most likely, what you are experiencing is that  the `<?` is not being
>   parsed by the PHP engine and being delivered to the browser. The
>   browser is then treating it as an unknown tag and ignoring it.
>
> The solutions are:
>
> 1. Don't use short tags as they are not turned on for all PHP installations. If you have >  `<? some code` change it to `<?php some code`
>
>    2.Make sure you are trying to run your PHP on a server that supports PHP.

Try installing XAAMP, It will install everything you need for PHP Development.

Oh! I think you're saving it as `.PHP` with capital letters, Don't use capital letters, Use small letters, so your file name should look something like `test.php`.

Comment: should my computer support it? no server being used.

Comment: What are you using? XAAMP?

Comment: correct, you need to have a server program running. Try WAMP or XAMPP on windows platforms -- they are free and install easily.